# Where does $scope function argument comes from?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the following snippet I can't understand a few basic details. 
When you declare a function, between parentheses you put usually placeholders. 
In this case, `$scope` is a placeholder. But also a reserved word.

```
var messages = {};
messages.someText = 'You have started your journey.';
function TextController($scope) {
  $scope.messages = messages;
}
```

Why not writing simply

```
function TextController() { 
  $scope.messages = messages;
}
```

Where does the `$scope` argument come from? Who's emitting it?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read any documentation at all on angular? Jumping into code is good, asking questions is great but reading basic documentation on a language first is even better.https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope and the variables "between the parentheses" aren't "placeholders", they generally referred to as arguments. You pass parameters to a function so you can use them rather than use global variables which can be messy.

Comment: Agree with @scrappedcola. You need to familiarise yourself with the basic of angularjs, how it works...in specific to the MVVM pattern. Try watching this to get a basic understand of angular - [AngularJs in 60min](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/angularjs-in-60-ish-minutes-the-ebook).

Comment: Thanks guys, actually the code is coming from a book called AngularJs by Brad Green (and Shyam Seshadri).

Answer (score 3):

`$scope` is not a global variable, so you syntax would throw an error.

Please look at how [Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) works in Angular:

> DI is pervasive throughout Angular. You can use it when defining components or when providing run and config blocks for a module.

Angular knows when to inject arguments to your function when your functions are Angular components such as services, directives, filters etc; so when Angular sees you got a controller function with `$scope` in its declaration, it knows to inject the correct `$scope` when it call it.

Notice that in your code you wouldn't be able to find $scope because you use it in a normal function, not in some kind of Angular component. I suspect you missed some Angular basics, so you should learn some more a then you will understand the problem in your code, which is basic Angular.

Answer (score 0):

It will throw error .i think you have to declare it in controller like this :
angular.module('myApp').controller('myContrroler', [ '$scope']);